# Matplotlib xtick ytick

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

plt.plot([1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24], color='black', marker=None)

labels = ['1', '2', '4', '8', '12', '16', '20', '24']
xticks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
nthreads = [1,2,4,8,12,16,20,24]

plt.xticks(xticks, labels)
plt.yticks(nthreads, labels)

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to produce a graph of f(x) = x but I can't get rid of the bend in the line. There's also a right shift of the x-axis tick labels.

How do I make a straight line through the points (1,1), (2,2), ..., (24, 24) and fix the x-axis label shifting?

[image: Plot generated by the code above]

I've tried all the other permutations of `nthreads` and `xticks` for `plt.xticks()` and `plt.yticks()`, respectively, and none of the results look as close to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you plot without setting x array matplotlib use default list like `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Therefore you do not get a straight line. You have to specify both arrays `x` and `y`. In your case they have to be the same.

If you want to put labels use the positions and labels like in this example. To shift you coordinate system set `xlim` and `ylim` of a current axis (`plt.gca()`).

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# plot y=x
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
x = [1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24]
plt.plot(x,x, color='black', marker=None)
# put labels for all ticks
labels = np.arange(1,25,1)
plt.xticks(labels, labels)
plt.yticks(labels, labels)
# set limits of axis
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([1,24])
ax.set_ylim([1,24])

plt.show()
```

[image]